# How to target all inputs on the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to target all input `type="number"` on the page however only the first one is being fired. Does anyone knows why and how I can target all input elements?

My JS:

```
// Select your input element.
var numInput = document.querySelector('input');

// Listen for input event on numInput.
numInput.addEventListener('input', function(){
    // Let's match only digits.
    var num = this.value.match(/^\d+$/);
    if (num === null) {
        // If we have no match, value will be empty.
        this.value = "";
    }
}, false)
```

**[My jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brunodd/fffv6eg4/)**

Comment: Why don't you try jQuery?  which has very short syntax 

$('input[type=number]')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [**querySelectorAll**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to select all the elements matching selector. To select all the input type `number` elements.

```
var allNumberInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="number"]');
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/fffv6eg4/1/)

Then you need to update the code that binds event on the elements. 
Loop over all the matched elements and bind the event on each of the element individually.

```js
// Select your input element.
var numInput = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="number"]');

for (var i = 0, len = numInput.length; i < len; i++) {
  // Listen for input event on numInput.
  numInput[i].addEventListener('input', function() {
    // Let's match only digits.
    var num = this.value.match(/^\d+$/);
    if (num === null) {
      // If we have no match, value will be empty.
      this.value = "";
    }
  }, false);
}
```

```html
<label for="first">First</label>
<br>
<input type="number" min="0" />
<br>
<br>
<label for="Second">Second</label>
<br>
<input type="number" min="0" />
```

---

If you have **jQuery** included on page

```
$('input[type="number"]')
```

**Demo**

```js
$('input[type="number"]').on('input', function(e) {
  // Let's match only digits.
  var num = this.value.match(/^\d+$/);
  if (num === null) {
    // If we have no match, value will be empty.
    this.value = "";
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="first">First</label>
<br>
<input type="number" min="0" />
<br>
<br>
<label for="Second">Second</label>
<br>
<input type="number" min="0" />
```

---

I'll suggest you to use **HTML5 pattern** attribute to allow only numeric values.

```
<input type="number" min="0" pattern="\d+" />
```

Comment: I had forgot about the loop event, you are right. Thank you! That worked. I am marking this one as correct, however all other answers should work too but yours makes more sense to me. =)

Comment: @brunodd Welcome! If you've jQuery loaded use jQuery approach, as in the second code snippet in the answer, if not then remove the jQuery tag

Comment: `<input type="number" min="0" pattern="\d+" />`. I didn't know. Thanks

Comment: @SheraliTurdiyev Welcome :)

Answer (score 3):

Use `document.querySelectorAll()` instead of `document.querySelector()`.

The `querySelectorAll()` method returns all of the matching elements, whereas the `querySelector()` method only returns the first one, which is what you're getting.

Answer (score 2):

[`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) only returns *one* element: the first matching element.

You can use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), instead. Then attach the event listener to the returned elements.

If you also want to filter the inputs on their type, use this:

```
var numInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=number]');
```

Then you can add the event listeners like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < numInputs .length; i++) {
    numInputs[i].addEventListener("click", yourFunction, false);
}
```

---

Now, since you're using jQuery, one might as well take advantage of that:

```
$('body').on('input', 'input[type=number]', yourFunction);
```

That's all you need.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery this is easy:

```
$('input[type=number]')
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is jQuery tagged you can use an [`attribute equals selector`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

> Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value
>   exactly equal to a certain value.

Code:

```
$('input[type="number"]').on('input',function(){
    // Let's match only digits.
    var num = this.value.match(/^\d+$/);
    if (num === null) {
        // If we have no match, value will be empty.
        this.value = "";
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/31t2Lafw/

If possibile tend to avoid the usage of new or poorly supported events like `input`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input

Comment: @Cerbrus new for me too: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input found in this question

Comment: I would advice against using features like that that are poorly supported. Or at least add in a notification mentioning it.

Comment: @Cerbrus yep I agree with you, but is in the OP code

Comment: Oh, you're totally right! I overlooked that.

Comment: @Cerbrus no problem, as usual I learned another thing here :-)